# How to wait for a static string to get a particular value

Tags: android, static-variables

I am new to android studio and my problem might sound pretty simple but I do badly need a solution.
I need to check whether my static string's value is equal to 1 before executing a particular block of code. It updates every 500ms. It goes from 1 to 16 and then back to 1.
I tried countdowntimer but it didn't work. Please help.
Edit:This is what i am trying.

```
store=findViewById(R.id.store);
    store.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++){
                String m=s;
                if (m.equals("1")) {
                    store();
                    break;
                } else {
                    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // this code will be executed after 2 seconds
                        }
                    }, 500);
                }
        }
        }
    });
```

Comment: what you tried yet? share your code please.

Comment: I have added my code in my post

Comment: you need to use any kind of observer pattern. e.g. local broadcast which listens to the custom event generated by the program or some interface triggered when the value matches to your requirement.

Comment: Can you explain it with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked for me. Thank you everyone for your time.

```
store=findViewById(R.id.store);
    store.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                String m=s;
                if (m.equals("1")) {
                    store();
                } else {
                    int i=Integer.parseInt(m);
                    i=(17-i)*delay;
                    new CountDownTimer(i, 1) {
                        public void onFinish() {
                            store();
                        }
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        }
                    }.start();
                }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

So essentially what you want to do is, you want to observe the value right?

What you can do instead is, every time you change the value, you invoke a callback, or already explicitly call your block of code.

```
// this gets called  every 500 ms
public static void updateMyValue(String value){
  MY_STATIC_STRING = value;
  callMyBlockOfCode();
}
```

Comment: Can you check my Code and tell me what I am doing wrong?